# Problem running a jQuery application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm developing a jQuery mobile application.  The application is developed in JavaScript, jQuery, and HTML. When I debug the application in browser using Firebug (in Firefox) it's working fine, but it doesn't run normally?  Is there a reason it's running in debug mode only?

Comment: `console.log` stops working in IE, but never heard like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is worded somewhat confusingly so I'm not quite sure what you mean but I think you might be running into a problem with `console.XXX()` statements in your JS - on a browser that doesn't have `console` defined (like IE) or a Firefox installation that doesn't have Firebug, `console` will be undefined and your JavaScript code is likely to fail if you have forgotten to comment out your logging statements. You can verify if that is the problem by commenting out all calls to `console` (or by watching the console and looking for log output).

A long term solution might be to define the console object when your JavaScript initially loads if it finds that the `console` doesn't exist - this way, even if you forget to comment out calls to `console` and someone who doesn't have Firebug installed or is using a different browser tries to use your code, they won't run into this issue. Take a look [at this blog post](http://blog.patspam.com/2009/the-curse-of-consolelog)